# C# WPF Change grid background image

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I change grid background image of clicked button? I tried this code but it didn't work. I need help.

Code:

```
WpfApplication5.Properties.Settings.Default.GridImage = "Pictures\file.jpg";
```

Comment: I'm said "Background Image" not color

Comment: The question is unclear: please include XAML and C# code snippet related to that Button click event. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Rick I tried this but not worked.

Comment: Can you please post the error message you get and the code of your button Click event.

Answer (score 1):

Background can be set by using ImageBrush:

```
    var imgBrush = new ImageBrush();

    imgBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Pictures\file.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    myGrid.Background = imgBrush;
```

When using relative path, you need to have Pictures folder with file.jpg in **bin\Debug folder.**

Answer (score 0):

Like this.You should set `Background` of `Button`

```
 <Grid>
      <Button Name="button1" Click="button1_Click">
      </Button>
  </Grid>

 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("image path", UriKind.Relative);
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(uri);
            button2.Background = new ImageBrush(img );
        }
```